# DBCP (DataBase Connection Pooling) from JavaSE with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, database-connection, connection-pooling, persistence.xml

For a JavaSE client, how is DBCP handled?  With JDBC, I know how to add Apache DBCP.  Can I add Apache DBCP to JPA?  If so, how?

Does the `persistence.xml` file have an option for this?

code:

```
package legacy.database;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

public class MyQueries {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyQueries.class.getName());
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LegacyDatabasePU");
    private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    public MyQueries() {
    }

    private List<Clients> findAll() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Clients c");
        List<Clients> clients = q.getResultList();
        em.close();
        return clients;
    }

    public List<Clients> selectByCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Clients> clientCriteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Clients.class);
        Root<Clients> clientRoot = clientCriteriaQuery.from(Clients.class);
        clientCriteriaQuery.select(clientRoot);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.phone1), "%" + criteria.getPhone1() + "%"));
        if (!criteria.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.status), "%" + criteria.getStatus() + "%"));
        }
        clientCriteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        List<Clients> clients = em.createQuery(clientCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
        em.close();
        return clients;
    }

    public Clients findById(int id) {
        Clients client = em.find(Clients.class, id);
        em.close();
        return client;
    }

}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="LegacyDatabasePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>legacy.database.Clients</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/legacy?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="gjkgjtd"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="jdbc"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm not using Tomcat, nor other container.

Comment: Take a look at [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) and look down for the various configuration options - including **Example property file:**.

Comment: I see `maximumPoolSize` but don't see the example yet..

Comment: Hint, it has it's own section titled "Example property file:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your persistence.xml,you create an EntityManagerFactory using the connection URL, driver name and the username/password to use, this doesn't necessarily pool the connections.So you cannot add Apache DBCP to JPA without using Spring or other platform like [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/datastore_connection.html). If you using with hibernate, you can configure hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml likes this,

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxActive">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">0</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Ok...so, if I switch to java. SE and hibernate, is there some form of DBCP. available?

Comment: except that is Hibernate-specific and he said JPA. So you could easily change your code example to be for persistence.xml (i.e the same persistence properties but in a persistence.xml file)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can pass a data source from your code, as [this blog post](http://onpersistence.blogspot.de/2008/04/eclipselink-and-datasources.html) shows.

Comment: Datasource is in toplink?  It allows. Connection. Pooling?

Comment: You just need to edit your code to pass an additional Map with one entry with key PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE and your instantiated DataSource as value. The latter in your case should be a DBCPDataSource. Note that this is the only entry you want to put in the map.

Comment: the blog post is about eclipselink.  do I need to switch from toplink to eclipselink to do this?

Comment: I haven't used TopLink yet, but as the API in question is standard JPA, it should work with just about every JPA implementation I can think of.

Comment: ok.  it looks like `ClientDataSource` is just for derby, I'm using MySQL, I'll have to google a bit tomorrow.  looks interesting :)